# Search windows updates with WUApiLib

Tags: c#, windows, com

How to get only mandatory updates and optional updates by turns? In other words how do I divide into important and unimportant (optional) updates like at the picture [image]

IUpdateSearcher interface has [Search function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386526%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but I can't find a criteria to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Old post, I know, but I've been searching for this answer myself. The easiest way I have found is to build your own search critera ([MSDN Search Method Criteria](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386526(v=vs.85).aspx)).

```
UpdateSession session = new UpdateSession(machineName);
IUpdateSearcher searchResults = session.CreateUpdateSearcher();

searchResults.ServerSelection = ServerSelection.ssWindowsUpdate;
searchResults.IncludePotentiallySupersededUpdates = false;
searchResults.Online = false;

// Set your criteria
ISearchResult result = searcher.Search("IsInstalled=0 AND IsHidden=0");
```

Use the ISearchResult to get a count, name etc of the updates.

To find optional updates, use "BrowseOnly=1 AND IsInstalled=0" for your criteria